# Como unir 2 Json en 1

Tags: php, mysql, json

Buenas, tengo un archivo php que me genera esto:

["1","Raul","Martinez","Perez","8.2","0","masculino","34","primavera 21"]

["65","Mi Ubicacion Actual","Calle 5 Naucalpan", "19.4694766998291", "-99.23297119140625","19.4689194","-99.2242569","30.93","1","3","Pendiente"]

y quisiera obtener esto:

["1","Raul","Martinez","Perez","8.2","0","masculino","34","primavera 21","65","Mi Ubicacion Actual","Calle 5 Naucalpan", "19.4694766998291", "-99.23297119140625","19.4689194","-99.2242569","30.93","1","3","Pendiente"]

no encuentro nada que me funcione, este es mi código:

```
if($resultset= getSQLResultSet("SELECT * FROM `Operador` WHERE id_operador='$id' LIMIT 1"))
{
    while($row=$resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
}
if($resultset2= getSQLResultSet("SELECT * FROM `Viajes_Pendientes` WHERE status='$status' LIMIT 1"))
{
    while($row2=$resultset2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        echo json_encode($row2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Utiliza la función `array_merge` si lo que ya tienes es un array y no un JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

y que tal si intentas hacer lo siguiente:

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();

if($resultset= getSQLResultSet("SELECT * FROM `Operador` WHERE id_operador='$id' LIMIT 1"))
{
    while($row=$resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        $array1 = $row;
    }
}
if($resultset2= getSQLResultSet("SELECT * FROM `Viajes_Pendientes` WHERE status='$status' LIMIT 1"))
{
    while($row2=$resultset2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        $array2 = $row2;
    }
}

$resultado = array_merge($array1, $array2);

echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: Buenas, gracias por responder pero no me funciona, el resultado sigue siendo: [["1","Raul","Martinez","Perez","8.2","0","masculino","34","primavera 21"],["65","Mi Ubicacion Actual","Calle 5 Naucalpan","19.4694766998291","-99.23297119140625","19.4689194","-99.2242569","30.93","1","3","Pendiente"]]  y lo necesito como si fuera un solo registro: 
["1","Raul","Martinez","Perez","8.2","0","masculino","34","primavera 21","65","Mi Ubicacion Actual","Calle 5 Naucalpan","19.4694766998291","-99.23297119140625","19.4689194","-99.2242569","30.93","1","3","Pendiente"]  Pero Gracia.

Comment: Te acabo de editar la respuesta con otra forma de hacerlo, espero te funcione

Comment: Si amigo, de verdad muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder, esta ultima modificación si me sirvió.

Comment: Si la respuesta sirvió para tu solución te invito a que la marques como aceptada para que los futuros desarrolladores sepan que fue una solución correcta al problema y lo puedan implementar., además te invito a que hagas el [Tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y te leas [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), saludos !